# When you're thinking of two different words and mispronounce one because you are still thinking of the other

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe this situation?

ex. A coworker just said the word meander, but pronounced it similar to wander because he was thinking of both word and decided to go with one over the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a type of phonemic speech error known as *blending.*

An example from the [Cognitive Science department of USCD](http://www.cogsci.ucsd.edu/%7Ecoulson/Courses/101c/production1.pdf) is:

> *blend of
> slick
> and
> slippery
> becomes
> slickery*

[Speech Errors as Linguistic Evidence](https://books.google.com.sg/books/about/Speech_Errors_as_Linguistic_Evidence.html?id=nP_-YEFoxCkC&redir_esc=y) defines *blending* as:

> *A blend is a word formed from two other words (very rarely more than two) by dividing each of the two original words into two parts, and combining one part from each original word into the new word called the blend.*

The book goes on to note that indecision about *synonyms* is a frequent factor, as well as other similarities between words.

In the example provided, mea**nder** and wa**nder** have an identical phonetic component, and are synonymous.

Answer (score 1):

If the words have similar sounds, then this would be an example of a:

## Malapropism

> The mistaken use of a word in place of a similar-sounding one, often
> with an amusing effect (e.g. ‘dance a flamingo’ instead of flamenco).

([OLD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/malapropism))

Answer (score 1):

This was the 'original'  meaning of *portmanteau word*, as coined by [Lewis Carroll](http://literature.org/authors/carroll-lewis/the-hunting-of-the-snark/preface.html), but I fear it has been forcibly twisted by those with no love for language to mean just `combination words'.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can say they "mixed" or "jumbled" the words up, but there is no specific single word for such a situation. At least, if there is, I'm definitely not aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try :

> [***discombobulate***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/discombobulate)
>   VERB North American 
>   humorous 
>   Disconcert or confuse (someone)
>
> ‘he is looking a little pained and discombobulated’

also defined

> [discombobulate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/discombobulated)
>   [dis-kuh m-bob-yuh-leyt]
>
> verb (used with object), discombobulated, discombobulating.
>   1.
>   to confuse or disconcert; upset; frustrate:
>
> *The speaker was completely discombobulated by the hecklers.*

It's the right combination of slightly flustered without losing composure... just a normal human trip-up